# Batching items using Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm trying to pack some integers into one using the Chinese Reminder Theorem. Taking the example below:

The integers that I want to pack are : {3,6,4}.

Using the theorem, we have :

- $\chi \equiv 3 \mod {5}$
- $\chi \equiv 6 \mod {7}$
- $\chi  \equiv 4 \mod {11}$

  and, I found $\chi = 48$

Cloud you please let me know if there is a method to found the three number 3, 6, and 4 if we have just 48  and the list {5,7,11}?

Comment: $48\not\equiv2\mod5$

Comment: If you want to pack $5,7,11$ they should be on the RHS of the congruence, not in the modulus.  Please fix the typos in your question.

Comment: Thank you J.W. Tanner. I edit the qustion. It is 3 not 2.

Comment: taking remainders isn't obvious ?

Answer (score 1):

$$48=5\cdot 9+3\\
48=7\cdot 6+6\\
48=11\cdot 4+4$$

The last part in each are the congruence classes used. That's how we would find the answer for such a small example.